# Why my bridge cannot be found?

Tags: networking, interface, network-bridge

I am setting a bridge on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install and it fails at "finding the device".

It is configured in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto testing0
iface testing0 inet static
  bridge_ports none
  address 10.20.2.254
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 10.20.2.255
```

When (re)starting the service I get a strange error:

```
# ifup testing0 --verbose
Parsing file /etc/network/containers
Configuring interface testing0=testing0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ IF_BOND_SLAVES=
+ [  ]
+ [  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exit
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
/bin/ip addr add 10.20.2.254/255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.20.2.255          dev testing0 label testing0
Cannot find device "testing0"
Failed to bring up testing0.
```

This is the first time I see such an issue (other bridges on other Ubuntu 16.04 set up the same way are fine). **What could be the reason for the error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing `bridge-utils`.

```
# apt install bridge-utils
```

fixed the issue.